# Programmatically find and change html on pages in my Plone site

Tags: plone

I want to search for all documents inside a fairly large Plone site that **contain a specific snippet of html** in the body (list items with headings inside them, urgh ...) **and then change that html** (drop the headings).

Pointers on how to do that are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a browserview (or run the instance in debug mode) and run this code:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
import re


ctool = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
results = ctool.searchResults(portal_type='Document')
for i in results:
    obj = i.getObject()
    text = obj.getField('text').get(obj)
    <find and remove your html using the regular expression module>
    obj.reindexObject()
```

If you need to do this many times, you could evaluate to add your [custom index](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/custom-indexing-strategies) that simplify the job.

Comment: Thanks! Could i also use lxml.html for this (as the html formatting is a bit hard to catch with a regex). Are there docs on how to use that module inside Plone?

Comment: Here's how to include it in your buildout: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.lxml . After that you simply import it in your code and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it in a while, but check out [GoReplace](http://plone.org/products/goreplace)